# .NET properties in IronPython classes

Tags: azure, ironpython, azure-table-storage

So I want to create my own Azure Table class that uses only IronPython for declaration. To define such class in C# i use property. How to translate it straight into pythonic way?

I now that when I overrride C# class all properties thanks to reflection to get_Name and set_Name and in this way I can override them. But I want to create new Properties visible in C#. [1](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#extensions-to-net-types)

In Python there is property function to create such. But will python property be recognize by C#? I can setter and getter functions rename to C# reflection model. [2](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)

Maybe in assemblies there are some way to create property in other way then syntactic sugar? I didn't find it.

I want to show that there is possibility to use Azure Tables in only IronPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Iron Python. This blog post may help, but it requires us to define the data model in C# and then invoke the data model from Iron Python: http://blog.sharpthinking.com.au/post/2009/02/20/Azure-Table-Storage-in-IronPython.aspx. In the end, table storage is a REST service. So we can use the REST APIs to work with table storage in any language of our choice. If it doesn't offer a client library in the language of our choice, we can build our own. Some third party libraries for OData may also help, as table storage uses OData protocol. I would recommend you to have a look at http://code.google.com/p/odata-py/.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After tries to run it directly on IronPython I realized that it is impossible to run Azure Tables directly on IronPython. I wanted to avoid using C# but it is impossible. Thanks that IronPython can use assemblies in C# I avoid this problem in similar way like in first link. Thanks for solution with OData, I think it would be better. And now why I can't done it plain in IronPython. Even I can create properties in Python way they don't have type.

Comment: Table storage is a REST service that implements OData protocol. So we can use it in any language that supports HTTP requests. As for how to convert IronPython types to the request body of the REST service, it is a client side task instead of a service side task. In C#, Microsoft has done the client side task for us by writing a client library. In IronPython, you may need to write your own or find a third party library. I’ll leave this part of the question to someone more familiar with IronPython.